# Best practices for technically executing AB testing on ecommerce site?

Tags: ab-testing, product-design, agile

I am working on a site redesign for my company's ecommerce site. We sell access to upcoming and recorded webinars. As a part of this redesign, I have recommended a new product strategy in which webinars can be bought from their product pages using an add to cart button. Currently, the product pages have 5 radio buttons indicating each different type of webinar access the customer can purchase (Longer webinar access, shorter webinar access, and CD-ROM copy to name a few).

My redesigned product page has just an add to cart button with the remaining "add-ons" displayed in the add to cart confirmation popup where they can be added to the webinar purchase.

I'm not sure if displaying the add-ons on the detail page is the way to go or if they should be presented in a add to cart pop-up (to reduce clutter and excess decision points at the point of ATC).

Now my question is, how would I work with an IT dept to deploy a test like this that depends on backend code to generate the different experiences and how would the test be executed with our testing platform, Adobe Target.

Our IT dept deploys site updates once a month. Has anyone executed something like this before? I so, how did you do it? Did you use Javascript to execute different scripts on the website in order to display the add-ons in either location? Wondering how I should give direction to IT to have them set this up so it can be easily tested with Adobe Target.

Thanks in advance. Happy to clarify any questions or comments.

Comment: Right now this looks like an Adobe Target question, so it's better if you ask their support. Product implementation questions are off topic here, and the answers we can give you maybe won't work in your specific environment. For example, I know how to do this, but never used Adobe Target, so I don't know if it's even remotely possible. Edit: this is 5 months old, "well played" UX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

There is some Toogle Solutions for A/B test,
But why you don't back few steps?
And make a prototype and learn with that, ask some users

Your scenario is delicate, imagine if the users don't like, you need wait to a month to fix?

Comment: That’s a fair point. I guess I’m saying have IT create both experiences and then somehow serve one or the other add on experience via Adobe Target. My question surrounds the execution of that part. We shouldn’t just deploy one solution and wait a month for them to develop the second part for testing.

Comment: Ok
In my opinion you should deploy the two parts at the same time, to both users experiment the same conditions. The software you are using will select randomly the users.

Facebook, Instagram do this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question probably depends on a conversation with your IT dept. There are so many different ways to set this up, picking the best way depends on what systems you have in place.

- If you're on a CMS that functionality could exist or be added via a script
- If you're using any automated marketing tools they usually have A/B Testing Features baked in
- Off the shelf tools just for A/B Testing
- I currently work on a windows application that releases every 6 months, all our A/B testing is completely home-brew code